# Trim \cdashline from arydshln package

Tags: tables, rules, arydshln

Is there a way to apply left or right trimming to the `\cdashline` from the `arydshln` package, similar to `\cmidrule(lr)`?

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{arydshln}
    \setlength\dashlinedash{0.5pt}
    \setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
    \newcommand{\cdotline}[1]{\noalign{\vskip\abovetopsep}\cdashline{#1}\noalign{\vskip\belowrulesep}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}rrr@{}}
        \cdotline{2-3}
        Test & Test & Test \\
        \cmidrule(l){2-3}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a command `\cdashedline` which inserts *trimed* dashed lines. The syntax is the syntax of `\cline`. It should be compatible with `longtable`.

I have not done the tuning for a behaviour exactly similar to `booktabs` and `arydshln` but it's easy to do if wanted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{longtable}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand { \cdashedline } { }
  { 
    \noalign { \skip_vertical:n { 3 mm } }
    \__johan_cline_i:nn 1 
  }
\cs_set:Npn \__johan_cline_i:nn #1 #2 { \__johan_cline_i:w #1-#2 \q_stop }
\cs_set:Npn \__johan_cline_i:w #1-#2-#3 \q_stop
  {
    \int_compare:nNnT { #1 } < { #2 }
      { \multispan { \int_eval:n { #2 - #1 } } & }
    \multispan { \int_eval:n { #3 - #2 + 1 } }
      { 
        \skip_horizontal:N \tabcolsep
        \xleaders 
        \hbox 
          {  
            \vrule height 0.4pt depth 0pt width 2pt 
            \kern 1pt 
          } 
        \hfill 
        \vrule height 0.4pt depth 0pt width 2pt 
        \skip_horizontal:N \tabcolsep
      }
    \peek_meaning_remove_ignore_spaces:NTF \cdashedline
      { & \exp_args:Ne \__johan_cline_i:nn { \int_eval:n { #3 + 1 } } }
      { 
        \everycr { } \cr 
        \noalign { \skip_vertical:n { 3 mm } }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{cccc}
text & text & other text & more text \\
text & text & other text & more text \\
text & text & other text & more text \\
\cdashedline{2-3} \cdashedline{4-4} 
text & text & other text & more text \\
text & text & other text & more text \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

In `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 4.0 of 2020-05-08), you can draw with Tikz whatever rule you want using the PGF/Tikz nodes created by `nicematrix` under the tabular.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{rrr}
Test & Test & Test \\
Test & Test & Test \\
\cmidrule(l){2-3}
\CodeAfter
\tikz [dotted , shorten < = \cmidrulekern]
  \draw [shorten < = \cmidrulekern] (2-|2) -- (2-|4) ;
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: If you want a macro for such a construction, tell me.

Comment: I should've mentioned it, but I need to use the `longtable` environment.